# What's the difference between print(f' and f' in Python?

Tags: python

What is the difference between the two? They both seem to produce the same output

```
name = 'Bob'

print(f'Hello {name}!')

f'Hello {name}!'
```

Comment: They only look similar in an interactive Python shell. In a script the second version won't print anything.

Comment: i think you are testing this in python interpreter directly, so you see no difference, save all these in a python file and run that , you will find the error occur

Comment: Even in the interactive interpreter they do not produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

The second one only prints when you use it in the REPL (interactive Python; `python -i`; sometimes available in development tools). In this case, the second one prints the string wrapped with single-quote, and the first one gives the string with no quote marks.

Otherwise, the second one does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

First case it will print output
and
In second case will not affect output if you write that in .py file